# login with twitter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller/tweet_test.php

```
class Tweet_test extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        // It really is best to auto-load this library!
        $this->load->library('tweet');

        // Enabling debug will show you any errors in the calls you're making, e.g:
        $this->tweet->enable_debug(TRUE);

        // If you already have a token saved for your user
        // (In a db for example) - See line #37
        // 
        // You can set these tokens before calling logged_in to try using the existing tokens.
        // $tokens = array('oauth_token' => 'foo', 'oauth_token_secret' => 'bar');
        // $this->tweet->set_tokens($tokens);


        if ( !$this->tweet->logged_in() )
        {
            // This is where the url will go to after auth.
            // ( Callback url )

            $this->tweet->set_callback(site_url('tweet_test/auth'));

            // Send the user off for login!
            $this->tweet->login();
        }
        else
        {
            // You can get the tokens for the active logged in user:
            // $tokens = $this->tweet->get_tokens();

            // 
            // These can be saved in a db alongside a user record
            // if you already have your own auth system.
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        echo 'hi there';
    }

    function auth()
    {
        $tokens = $this->tweet->get_tokens();

        // $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentiaaaaaaaaals');
        // 
        // Will throw an error with a stacktrace.

        $user = $this->tweet->call('get', 'account/verify_credentials');
        var_dump($user);

        $friendship     = $this->tweet->call('get', 'friendships/show', array('source_screen_name' => $user->screen_name, 'target_screen_name' => 'elliothaughin'));
        var_dump($friendship);

        if ( $friendship->relationship->target->following === FALSE )
        {
            $this->tweet->call('post', 'friendships/create', array('screen_name' => $user->screen_name, 'follow' => TRUE));
        }

        $this->tweet->call('post', 'statuses/update', array('status' => 'Testing #CodeIgniter Twitter library by @elliothaughin - http://bit.ly/grHmua'));

        $options = array(
                    'count' => 10,
                    'page'  => 2,
                    'include_entities' => 1
        );

        $timeline = $this->tweet->call('get', 'statuses/home_timeline');

        var_dump($timeline);
    }
}
```

this is my config/tweet.php

```
config/tweet.php    <?php
$config['tweet_consumer_key'] = "jFLUGlTx0I392Y720rNPG6XsT";
$config['tweet_consumer_secret'] = "5ZGPByzLYYsro4zacVAYhXzDhOdKos4bC8qX3Z7bvMKwVcpRxs";
```

also created my apps on twitter and set its secrete key in my config/tweet.php file.
i got this error.

Whoa there!
There is no request token for this page. That's the special key we need from applications asking to use your Twitter account. Please go back to the site or application that sent you here and try again; it was probably just a mistake.

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't have the application key(API key) and application secret you won't be able to get what you want.

So First go to: https://dev.twitter.com/apps

2. Create a new application.
3. Fill out any required fields such as the application name and description.
4. Provide your desired URL as the Callback URL for your application:
5. Once you have registered, past the created application credentials (Customer Key(API key) and Application Secret) into the boxes above.

   It would be better if you provide a snippet of the problem what you are exactly facing.

Answer (score 0):

you normally need to signup with twitter, register an application to get access to consumer key and consumer secret code. Without seeing the php code its hard to see what you are trying already/what you have done so far